# Django forms - error messages displayed twice in template

Tags: django

As above, my template displays validation errors twice. I need to disable messages that appear below the fields by default (the one with font-weight)

img -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZYUm.jpg

template

```
   <div class="container">
        <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
                {{field|as_crispy_field}}
                {% if field.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ field.errors|striptags }}</div>
                    {{ form.name_of_field.errors }} 
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
    </div>
```

forms

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    repassword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = ForumUser
        fields = ["username", "email", "password", "repassword"]
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            new_data = {
                "placeholder": f"Provide {field}",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
            self.fields.get(field).widget.attrs.update(new_data)
            self.fields.get(field).help_text = ""
        
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserRegisterForm, self).clean()
        return cleaned_data
    
    def clean_repassword(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        repassword = self.cleaned_data.get("repassword")

        if repassword != password:
            raise ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the one with font-weight"?

Also please embed the image instead of linking it

Comment: Try removing "{{ form.name_of_field.errors }} "